# Simple post rating system on WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I am creating post voting system which will allow visitors to rate post (from 1 to 5). It is working fine if user is logged in, or there is no any caching plugin installed. But for guest with caching plugin activated (WP super cache) it is not working.

Can anybody help me to make it work for guest users too? I guess it needs some Ajax/JavaScript?

```
<form method='POST' action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="rate" value=2>
    <input type=submit value=2>
</form>
<form method='POST' action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="rate" value=3>
    <input type=submit value=3>
</form>
<form method='POST' action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="rate" value=4>
    <input type=submit value=4>
</form>
<form method='POST' action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="rate" value=5>
    <input type=submit value=5>
</form>

<? php
if (isset($_POST['rate'])) {
    if ($_POST['rate'] == '1') {
        $rate = get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'up', true);
        $rate = $rate + 1;
        update_post_meta($post - > ID, 'up', $rate);

        $total = get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'total', true);
        $ratetotal = $total + 1;
        update_post_meta($post - > ID, 'total', $ratetotal);
    }
    if ($_POST['rate'] == '2') {
        $rate = get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'up', true);
        $rate = $rate + 2;
        update_post_meta($post - > ID, 'up', $rate);

        $total = get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'total', true);
        $ratetotal = $total + 1;
        update_post_meta($post - > ID, 'total', $ratetotal);
    }
    if ($_POST['rate'] == '3') {
        $rate = get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'up', true);
        $rate = $rate + 3;
        update_post_meta($post - > ID, 'up', $rate);

        $total = get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'total', true);
        $ratetotal = $total + 1;
        update_post_meta($post - > ID, 'total', $ratetotal);
    }
    if ($_POST['rate'] == '4') {
        $rate = get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'up', true);
        $rate = $rate + 4;
        update_post_meta($post - > ID, 'up', $rate);

        $total = get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'total', true);
        $ratetotal = $total + 1;
        update_post_meta($post - > ID, 'total', $ratetotal);
    }
    if ($_POST['rate'] == '5') {
        $rate = get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'up', true);
        $rate = $rate + 5;
        update_post_meta($post - > ID, 'up', $rate);

        $total = get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'total', true);
        $ratetotal = $total + 1;
        update_post_meta($post - > ID, 'total', $ratetotal);
    }
}

$score = get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'up', true);
$number_of_votes = get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'total', true);
$average = round($score / $number_of_votes, 1);

echo $average;;
echo ' / 5 ';
echo " - ".get_post_meta($post - > ID, 'total', true)." votes"; ?>
```

Comment: Please, put quotes aroud your input type and name

Comment: You can use a loop in your php instead of getting a very long code like that..

Comment: @Hearner , attribute quotes are **optional** in HTML5 (although still recommended by most people).

Comment: @Hearner , I put quotes aroud your input type and name, like mevius said attribute quotes are optional in HTML5. Still, thanks both of you.